# mysql (mariadb) ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: linux, passwords, mysql, mariadb

I'm working on Xubuntu 15.04. I already installed the MariaDB-Server on various systems and was always asked for a root password during installation. This time, however, I don't remember being asked for the password. When I try to login without a password (or a blank password), I get the `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` error. 
I tried uninstalling the package completely by

```
sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server
```

When I reinstalled, I still didn't get asked for the root password.

I tried the `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` approach from
[mysql how to fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) .
I can modify the password for the root user in the mysql database - at least the hash value changes - but I still cannot login with the new password after a restart of the mysql-server. I still get the same error.

The user debian-sys-maint does not exist. So, I cannot use it to fix anything.

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: A helpful thread with the same question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem following the answer from this post:

[Can't reset MySQL (MariaDB) root password](https://superuser.com/questions/949496/cant-reset-mysql-mariadb-root-password)

One has to change the plugin field of mysql.user for all roots to a blank string.

Comment: This issue is described here: 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Comment: This approach will cause problems later.  If you disable the plug-in, the daily cron job will break as it's assuming it can log in with that plug-in.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 39):

You need to reset the password.
so for that

```
sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Comment: The non-obvious "magic" to this approach is that the root operating system user is able to log into the database without having to specify a password because `plugin: auth_socket` is enabled, by default. In other words, there is no need to use `--skip-grant-tables` as would have been necessary in MySQL versions past. (Also, technically, this measure is not "resetting the password"; it is disabling a plugin.)

Comment: +1, Can you explain about reason why?

Comment: This approach will cause problems later.  If you disable the plug-in, the daily cron job will break as it's assuming it can log in with that plug-in.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 11):

The idea with the new set-up is that you shouldn't be using passwords at all.  See [UNIX_SOCKET Authentication Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/) for details.

What's especially relevant is the contents of */usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.0/README.Debian.gz* on Ubuntu 16.04:

> On new installs no root password is set and no debian-sys-maint user is
>   created anymore. Instead the MariaDB root account is set to be authenticated
>   using the unix socket, e.g. any mysqld invocation by root or via sudo will
>   let the user see the mysqld prompt.
>
> You may never ever delete the mysql user "root". Although it has no password
>   is set, the unix_auth plugin ensure that it can only be run locally as the root
>   user.
>
> The credentials in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf specify the user which is used by the
>   init scripts to stop the server and perform logrotation. This used to be the
>   debian-sys-maint user which is no longer used as root can run directly.

So if you disable that plug-in for root and set a password, the daily cron job will break as it's assuming it will log in as root without a password, but with the plug-in.

Later it says:

> Scripts should run as a user have have the required grants and be
>   identified via unix_socket.

So it looks like passwords should no longer be used by applications.

Comment: I just encountered the very problem that you describe: `"So if you disable that plug-in for root and set a password, the daily cron job will break as it's assuming it will log in as root without a password..."` The non-obvious implication of the UNIX_SOCKET Authentication Plugin being enabled (which is now the default) is that one's ability to authenticate as the root database user *with a password* is disabled. Nowhere on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/ is this considerable limitation mentioned. Accordingly, it is impossible to login as root e.g. over SSH.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by running this command, right after installation:

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

At first step, password is blank, so just press Enter.

Comment: It's not blank if already set, which my forgotten pw is… so still can't log in

Comment: As I've mentioned it was "right after installation". A clean install, no password.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sudo mysql -u root` - that's it

---

Details: Newer versions authenticate to mysql using system authentication. So if you can sudo to the OS, it assumes you're db root too. You can confirm this by issuing `sudo mysql -u root -e "USE mysql; SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;"`. You should see something like this (maybe with `auth_socket` in other distros)

```
+------+-----------+-------------+
| User | Host      | plugin      |
+------+-----------+-------------+
| root | localhost | unix_socket |
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I'm logged in as root, but for me this command still wants the MariaDB root password… which I've forgotten :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a raapberry pi with stretch. My solution was to create a new user with all privileges by doing the following:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root

MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql
MariaDB [mysql]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL privileges ON mysql.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

Now I can login and us the user "admin" as superuser.

I hope this is going to help someone.